# SwiftUI set a Binding from the String result of a picker

Tags: ios, swiftui, picker

I am tearing out my hair trying to figure out how to bind the picked value in my SwiftUI view:

The picker needs to be bound to the Int returned from the tags. I need to covert this Int to the String and set the Binding. How?

```
struct ContentView: View {

   @Binding var operatorValueString:String

    var body: some View {

         Picker(selection: queryType, label: Text("Query Type")) {
             ForEach(0..<DM.si.operators.count) { index in
                 Text(DM.si.operators[index]).tag(index)
             }
         }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
    }
}
```

How and where can I set my operatorValueString ?

> operatorValueString = DM.si.operators[queryType] //won't compile.

Comment: Have you defined queryType somewhere, Picker is expecting a binding. BTW DM.si.operators.indices is easier to use than count. I don't like the segmented picker. I had to use a ObservedObject with a PassthroughSubject publisher as well to get it to work the way I wanted.

Comment: Got a sample to share? This is driving me mad.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can achieve the result, using your own custom binding that sets the string, whenever the picker's selection changes:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var operatorString = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Subview(operatorValueString: $operatorString)
            Text("Selected: \(operatorString)")
        }
    }
}

struct Subview: View {
    @Binding var operatorValueString: String
    @State private var queryType: Int = 0

    let operators = ["OR", "AND", "NOT"]

    var body: some View {

        let binding = Binding<Int>(
            get: { self.queryType },
            set: {
                self.queryType = $0
                self.operatorValueString = self.operators[self.queryType]
            })

        return Picker(selection: binding, label: Text("Query Type")) {
            ForEach(operators.indices) { index in
                Text(self.operators[index]).tag(index)
            }
        }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
    }
}
```

Comment: That is what I wound up doing. Seems like Picker should have another binding.

Comment: Unfortunately this led to a infinite loop when you come back and edit. How do you set the Binding to reflect the existing selection?

Comment: @jimijon I don't follow. What is the code that leads to an infinite loop?

Comment: I need to send overt in the binding the operatorValueString... then I need to set the binding to the proper number of the picker. However, that means I need to set self.querytype in the init, which then causes the loop. I must be missing something very obvious

Comment: this is what I used:

Comment: Amazing! I spent a whole day trying to do something like that using Combine, but that would just make @Binding cause an infinite loop by constantly recalculating body. For some reasons SwiftUI feels extremely hacky beyond the simplest of things.